# recipe for Magento site migration + SSL

Tags: database, magento, import

I am successfully importing Magento site from one domaine to another using a recipe summarized below.  It seem to work, but I am note sure if I am missing anything major that I may regret later.

Also one site is has SSL and proxy server enabled that cannot be turned off.  What additional steps are required to adapt this recipe to set up a SSL site (ie: change Magento "secure" and "unsecure" sections via sql and/other editing xml file?)

- import database
    mysql -u user -p -h localhost shop < /var/www/myshop/shopmsc_sql_dump.sql;
- import entire site - all text files to /shop
- repoint URLS
  UPDATE core_config_data SET value=’http://www.shop.com/’ WHERE path=’web/unsecure/base_url’ ;
  UPDATE core_config_data SET value=’http://www.shopc.com/’ WHERE path=’web/secure/base_url’;
- clean /var/cache and var/session
- turn on Magento caching
- fix /app/etc/local.xml - datbase stuff

  1

Comment: Just in case you are using some extension which have site based authentications in that case you might face some issues with those extensions else you are good to go.

Comment: You also have to repoint all your website if you have more than one website/store view in your Magento installation.

Comment: I am using multiple store views, and have not had problem

Comment: Your steps look accurate, there are lots of "migration" articles here on SO and the web that will confirm such.  I'm not really understanding what the specific question is here, however.